# Show device usage consent dialog in Unity app for Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I'm working on application for Hololens built on Unity. My need is to get some information from phone(android or wp - doesn't really matter) using `Bluetooth Service Port Profile`. The chosen approach is to make a Hololens act as Bluetooth Host. So I'm using `RfcommServiceProvider` for this. The simplified sample:

```cs
_rfcommProvider = await RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort);
_socketListener = new StreamSocketListener();
_socketListener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnectionReceived;
await _socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(_rfcommProvider.ServiceId.AsString(),
                                             SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);
_rfcommProvider.StartAdvertising(_socketListener, true);
```

And event handler like:

```
private async void OnConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    _socket = args.Socket;
    ...
}
```

The issue is next: when client device tries to connect - user need to grant permission for this app/device pair. If use this code in UWP app on hololens - system consent dialog appears. But when it's Unity app - it just failes on attempt to get socket in event handler. To fix this user need to close app, go to Settings > Privacy > Other devices and turn on switch button for device/app pair(this button appears there only after first attempt to connect to Hololens app).

So the question: is there a distinct way or some workaround to ask user for this permission inside Unity app?

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this issue? If I understand correctly, I can never use anything revolving networking as long as the user is manually consenting to the usage of capabilities... which does not pop up in Unity?

Comment: @Battle as far as I know with RS4 update they've added consent dialogs(at least now it appears for microphone permission) My issue was specific to `bluetooth` capability and permission(but I haven't checked if it pops consent dialog in RS4 yet). `internetClient` and `wifiControl` capabilities worked just fine without any consent.

Comment: I already figured out the issue I had. It was on Unity and using the main thread and having sole control over the UI, and on the networking on seemingly creating an own thread for the receiving end. But thanks for the answer anyway!