# HoloLens unable to send or receive data via BT and TCP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, virtual-reality

I am working on HoloLens (**Unity-UWP**) and trying to make a connection with PC (**UWP**) or Android phone work (**Xamarin**). So far I tried client and host with both Bluetooth and TCP (even two versions with different libraries) on Android and UWP. I kept the code entirely separated from user interface, so that it is easier to use, to understand and modular. An `Action<string>` is used to output results (error logs and sent messages).

Everything that is *not* on the HoloLens works fine (even though it's exactly the same code). It worked from PC (UWP) to Android with client and host switched. But it doesn't even work between HoloLens and PC (UWP). The behavior ranged from crashes (mostly for Bluetooth) to instant disconnection. The last tests resulted in disconnection once bytes are about to be received. It could even read the first 4 bytes (uint for the length of the following UTF-8 message), but then it was disconnected. The other devices seemed to work fine.

What I know: Capabilities are set, the code works, the issue is likely something that is common for everything that has to do with networking and HoloLens.

So the question is, is Unity or HoloLens incompatible with something I am using? What I used which is worth mentioning: StreamSocket, BinaryWriter, BinaryReader, Task (async, await). Or is HoloLens actively blocking communication with applications on other devices? I know it can connect to devices with Bluetooth and that it can connect via TCP, and it looks like people succeed to get it to work. Are there known issues? Or is there something with Unity that causes this - a bad setting maybe? Do I have to use async methods or only sync? Are there incompatibility issues with Tasks/Threads and Unity? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316321/show-device-usage-consent-dialog-in-unity-app-for-hololens) possibly the issue (inability to consent to permissions)?

Another thing to note is that I cannot ping HoloLens via its IP by using the cmd, even though the IP is correct.

I'd appreciate any advice, answer or guess. I can provide more information if requested (see also the comments below). I would suggest to focus on the **TCP connection** as it seemed to be working better and appears to be more "basic." Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;

#region Common
public abstract class TcpCore
{
    protected StreamSocket Socket;
    protected BinaryWriter BWriter;
    protected BinaryReader BReader;
    protected Task ReadingTask;

    public bool DetailedInfos { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Listening { get; protected set; }

    public ActionSingle<string> MessageOutput { get; protected set; } = new ActionSingle<string> (); // Used for message and debug output. They wrap an Action and allow safer use.
    public ActionSingle<string> LogOutput { get; protected set; } = new ActionSingle<string> ();

    protected const string USED_PORT = "1337";
    protected readonly Encoding USED_ENCODING = Encoding.UTF8;

    public abstract void Disconnect ();

    protected void StartCommunication ()
    {
        Stream streamOut = Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite ();
        Stream streamIn = Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead ();
        BWriter = new BinaryWriter (streamOut); //{ AutoFlush = true };
        BReader = new BinaryReader (streamIn);

        LogOutput.Trigger ("Connection established.");
        ReadingTask = new Task (() => StartReading ());
        ReadingTask.Start ();
    }

    public void SendMessage (string message)
    {
        // There's no need to send a zero length message.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (message)) return;

        // Make sure that the connection is still up and there is a message to send.
        if (Socket == null || BWriter == null) { LogOutput.Trigger ("Cannot send message: No clients connected."); return; }

        uint length = (uint) message.Length;
        byte[] countBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes (length);
        byte[] buffer = USED_ENCODING.GetBytes (message);

        if (DetailedInfos) LogOutput.Trigger ("Sending: " + message);

        BWriter.Write (countBuffer);
        BWriter.Write (buffer);
        BWriter.Flush ();
    }

    protected void StartReading ()
    {
        if (DetailedInfos) LogOutput.Trigger ("Starting to listen for input.");
        Listening = true;
        while (Listening)
        {
            try
            {
                if (DetailedInfos) LogOutput.Trigger ("Starting a listen iteration.");

                // Based on the protocol we've defined, the first uint is the size of the message. [UInt (4)] + [Message (1*n)] - The UInt describes the length of the message (=n).
                uint length = BReader.ReadUInt32 ();

                if (DetailedInfos) LogOutput.Trigger ("ReadLength: " + length.ToString ());

                MessageOutput.Trigger ("A");
                byte[] messageBuffer = BReader.ReadBytes ((int) length);
                MessageOutput.Trigger ("B");
                string message = USED_ENCODING.GetString (messageBuffer);
                MessageOutput.Trigger ("Received Message: " + message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // If this is an unknown status it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
                if (SocketError.GetStatus (e.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    // Seems to occur on disconnects. Let's not throw().
                    Listening = false;
                    Disconnect ();
                    LogOutput.Trigger ("Unknown error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Listening = false;
                    Disconnect ();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        LogOutput.Trigger ("Stopped to listen for input.");
    }
}
#endregion

#region Client
public class GTcpClient : TcpCore
{
    public async void Connect (string target, string port = USED_PORT) // Target is IP address.
    {
        try
        {
            Socket = new StreamSocket ();
            HostName serverHost = new HostName (target);
            await Socket.ConnectAsync (serverHost, port);

            LogOutput.Trigger ("Connection successful to: " + target + ":" + port);
            StartCommunication ();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogOutput.Trigger ("Connection error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public override void Disconnect ()
    {
        Listening = false;
        if (BWriter != null) { BWriter.Dispose (); BWriter.Dispose (); BWriter = null; }
        if (BReader != null) { BReader.Dispose (); BReader.Dispose (); BReader = null; }
        if (Socket != null) { Socket.Dispose (); Socket = null; }
        if (ReadingTask != null) { ReadingTask = null; }
    }
}
#endregion

#region Server
public class GTcpServer : TcpCore
{
    private StreamSocketListener socketListener;

    public bool AutoResponse { get; set; } = false;

    public async void StartServer ()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a StreamSocketListener to start listening for TCP connections.
            socketListener = new StreamSocketListener ();

            //Hook up an event handler to call when connections are received.
            socketListener.ConnectionReceived += ConnectionReceived;

            //Start listening for incoming TCP connections on the specified port. You can specify any port that's not currently in use.
            await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync (USED_PORT);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogOutput.Trigger ("Connection error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ConnectionReceived (StreamSocketListener listener, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            listener.Dispose ();
            Socket = args.Socket;
            if (DetailedInfos) LogOutput.Trigger ("Connection received from: " + Socket.Information.RemoteAddress + ":" + Socket.Information.RemotePort);
            StartCommunication ();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogOutput.Trigger ("Connection Received error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public override void Disconnect ()
    {
        Listening = false;
        if (socketListener != null) { socketListener.Dispose (); socketListener = null; }
        if (BWriter != null) { BWriter.Dispose (); BWriter.Dispose (); BWriter = null; }
        if (BReader != null) { BReader.Dispose (); BReader.Dispose (); BReader = null; }
        if (Socket != null) { Socket.Dispose (); Socket = null; }
        if (ReadingTask != null) { ReadingTask = null; }
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Greetings, Your server runs in PC I assume and client in HoloLens? Have you pinpoint which of the two has the strange behavior? Is it the Server that hangs first so the client disconnects or the client crashes? Also in StartReading I would add a log with (e.Message) outside of the if to make sure I log any generic error it might occur.

Comment: @S.Fragkos - With PC (Server) <-> HoloLens I can send messages to the PC, but when I try to send to HL it disconnects with an unknown error. Nothing in the log appears on the HL side. With HoloLens (Server) <-> PC it can connect, but nothing appears in the HL logs... until I try to send a message from there, then I get the message that it connected to [IP]:52643, which is the port it got from `Socket.Information.RemotePort`, whereas I consistently use 1337. The HoloLens side simply refuses to receive any messages and struggles with handling incoming connections.

Comment: @S.Fragkos - I got this error message though in the HL (Server) <-> PC testing: "get_isActiveAndEnabled can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene. Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers. Instead move initialization code to the Awake or State function." - That's clearly a Unity specific error message. Are my issues with Unity & Threading? I didn't actively use multithreading, so I wonder what could cause this, and if that is the issue at all.

Comment: @S.Fragkos - I adjusted it to add the exception message and received this with PC (Server) <-> HL: "Unknown error occurred: `Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.`" - It occurred when I attempted to send a message to HL, and after that it disconnected.

Comment: I have just done the BT stuff a few days ago, but I used RFCOMM classes and `DataReader` and `DataWriter` for it. I just followed the "Bluetooth RFCOMM chat sample" from https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat. The only thing I had a few problems was setting up the service IDs correctly on both sides.

Comment: One additional thing I just remembered: Setting the "Internet client & server" capability does not give you permission to talk in your local network, which was a bit surprising for me … There is a separate capability for local networks that you need to set.

Comment: Do you have InternetClient checked in the capability settings? Player Settings > Settings for Universal Windows Platform > Publishing Settings > Capabilities -> InternetClient

Comment: @slaphshot33324 - I found out what my issue was. The receiving end of Bluetooth and TCP seemed to create an own thread (maybe something else, but I didn't do it actively), which was unable to write on the main thread in Unity, which solely handles GameObjects (like the output log). Thus I got weird log outputs when I tested it on HoloLens. I had to create a new TCP code which works for Unity but not the Unity-UWP solution with TcpClient/TcpListener in order to find out what the issue was. I just had to use Unity's Update() method in order to set the text of the output. That was all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **Threading.**

For whoever may have similar issues, I found the solution. It was due to Unity itself, not HoloLens specifically. My issue was that I wrote my code separately in an own class instead of commingle it with UI code, which would have made it 1. unreadable and 2. not modular to use. So I tried a better coding approach (in my opinion). Everybody could download it and easily integrate it and have basic code for text messaging. While this was no issue for Xamarin and UWP, it was an issue for Unity itself (and there the Unity-UWP solution as well).

The receiving end of Bluetooth and TCP seemed to create an own thread (maybe even something else, but I didn't do it actively), which was unable to write on the main thread in Unity, **which solely handles GameObjects** (like the output log). Thus I got weird log outputs when I tested it on HoloLens.

I created a new TCP code which works for Unity but not the Unity-UWP solution, using TcpClient/TcpListener, in order to try another version with TCP connection. Luckily when I ran that in the editor it finally pointed on the issue itself: The main thread could not be accessed, which would have written into the UI - the text box for the log output. In order to solve that, I just had to use Unity's Update() method in order to set the text to the output. The variables themselves still could be accessed, but not the GameObjects.

Answer (score 2):

Coincidentially, I just implemented a BT connection between HoloLens and an UWP app. I followed the sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat.

As capabilities, I set "Bluetooth" (of course), "Internet (Client & Server)" and "Private Networks (Client & Server)". The steps on the server side then are:

1. Create an `RfcommServiceProvider` for your own or an existing (eg OBEX object push) service ID.
2. Create a `StreamSocketListener` and wire its `ConnectionReceived` Event.
3. Bind the service Name on the listener: `listener.BindServiceNameAsync(provider.ServiceId.AsString(), SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);`
4. If you have a custom service ID, set its name along with other attributes you may want to configure. See the sample linked above for this. I think, this is mostly optional.
5. Start advertising the BT service: `provider.StartAdvertising(listener, true);`

Once a client connects, there is a `StreamSocket` in the `StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs` that you can use to create a `DataReader` and `DataWriter` on like on any other stream. If you only want to allow one client, you can also stop advertising now.

On the client side, you would:

1. Show the `DevicePicker` and let the user select the peer device. Do not forget setting a filter like `picker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true));` You can also allow unpaired devices, but you need to call `PairAsync` before you can continue in step 2. Also, I think there is no way to circumvent the user consent dialogue in this case, so I would recommend pairing before. To be honest, I did not check whether the unpaired stuff works on HoloLens.
2. You get a `DeviceInformation` instance from the picker, which you can use to obtain a BT device like `await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(info.Id);`
3. Get the services from the device like `device.GetRfcommServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);` and select the one you are interested in. Note that I found that the built-in filtering did not behave as expected, so I just enumerated the result and compared the UUIDs manually. I believe that the UWP implementation performs a case-sensitive string comparison at some point, which might lead to the requested service not showing up although it is there.
4. Once you found your service, which I will call `s` from now on, create a `StreamSocket` and connect using `socket.ConnectAsync(s.ConnectionHostName, s.ConnectionServiceName, SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);`

Again, you can not create the stream readers and writers like on the server side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I could establish both a Bluetooth and TCP connection which I could test on PC (UWP application) to Android (Xamarin application) in both ways (server/client). It worked fine. My current suspicion is that it is about Unity and threading... and that the receiving end on HoloLens created its own thread which had no access to the main thread and caused an exception which was not displayed (until yesterday, vaguely).

Comment: Glad you solved it. That is always an issue when combining graphics and network. All built-in listeners and all awaited calls must be assumed to run in an arbitrary thread context. In some cases, you can control the thread with continuation contexts, but I usually have a queue for network-induced changes that is processed in the rendering thread before each Frame.

Comment: It was a harsh lesson, but valuable nonetheless (it took a lot of time and effort). If I think about it... in the Xamarin/Android application I incidentally solved this issue without knowing about it due to laziness (I kept everything as minimalistic as possible... I used one single button with a popup text which was provided when creating the project). In UWP I also had issues but resolved it at an early point. It's just that I had no editor to my disposal when testing it on HoloLens, and Unity uses TCP libraries which Unity-UWP can not.